Power BI :: Calendar Table doesn't have the calendar icon
I have a DAX code that can create a calendar table for me:
Calendar = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Calendar Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "Month Name", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
    "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] ),
    "Day", DAY ( [Date] ),
    "Quarter", "Q" & TRUNC ( ( MONTH ( [Date] ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1
)

Everything looks good, it's not even marked as date table but the result is perfect for me:

In another project I create the same calendar table, with the same code.
As you can see:

Name
Data Type
Format
Summarization are all the same

...but in the and as you can see the calendar is not the same. I can mark it or not as calendar table but the icon will still be the same: not a calendar icon but the general icon.

And If I try to create a hierarchy it results in creating this empty stuff:

What am I doing wrong?

You're doing nothing wrong. The first one you have, the report has Time intelligence: Auto date/time switched on:

It is recommended that you switch this off when you are using your own Date table. So your second option is recommended. Now with Auto date/time switched off, you will need to build your own Hierarchy.
Tip: For your Quarter column, you can use the QUARTER function:
"Quarter", "Q" & QUARTER([Date])


Thank you @Sam. Do you suggest to use a simple CALENDARAUTO() when Time Intelligence is enabled?

Personally, I never use Auto date/time. There isn't a need for it when you have your own Date table. See Apply auto date/time in Power BI Desktop for info on it. Fun fact, if Auto date/time is enabled and you mark a date table as a Date table, it essentially removes the Auto date/time functionality.

When your date table is not marked as a date table, Power BI will automatically create date hierarchies for you (as seen in your first image). Since you marked your second image as a date table, Power Bi removed the auto-generated hierarchy. If you want to use a hierarchy in your second image, you will need to create columns in your table instead.
Example:

More information here.
